# Can't Interact with Second External Monitor

Tags: display

I have connected two external monitors to my MacBook Pro through USB-C to an Anker docking station.  The displays appear to be arranged correctly in the settings (screenshot below)

In the image, Monitor 1 is my Macbook Pro.  Monitors 2 and 3 are external through the docking station.

The problem is, for some reason monitors 2 and 3 are 'mirrored' in the sense that their displays are identical.  However, I can drag my mouse from 2 to 3 as though they were extended.  I cannot actually interact with monitor 3 using the mouse however.

Any pointers to fix this bizarre behavior would be appreciated!  Thanks for looking

[image]

Comment: A couple of things - could you tell us which you consider to be 1, 2 & 3. Also, test grabbing a Finder window by the title bar & carrying the window with you across each of the 3 screens - what happens?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @Tetsujin.  Monitors 1, 2, and 3 are in order from the left

Comment: SO.  I am fortunate enough to have another monitor to try which is from a different manufacturer.  Replacing #3 with the monitor from the alternate manufacturer solves the problem.

Comment: It seems like OSX is getting confused having 2 displays with the same name or manufacturer model number?

Comment: @Tetsujin I can drag a window from 1 to 2, and 2 back to 1.  If i drag from 2 to 3, the window appears to go to drag somewhere, but does not display on 3.  It is all very bizarre.  I will post the "fix" of using a display from an alternate manufacturer/model as an answer when I get everything set up and it seems stable

Comment: I've also seen a lot of activity on my CPU because of the external monitors!  for some reason apple doesn't use the GPU at all for external monitors?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the program I wrote, [displayplacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer), which was developed to deal with the wonkiness of macOS screen layouts. For your particular situation, you'll want to run `displayplcer list` to output your current monitor setup. Then, edit that profile so that it isn't mirroring. Mirrored monitors are after the `+` sign in the `id` section. It'll take a bit of fiddling. Once you get it working though, you can assign that displayplacer command to a hotkey. Then, whenever this happens again (usually every time you plug in), type the hotkey to set your monitors to the correct layout.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case was to use a monitor from a different model/manufacturer for display #3.  When monitors 2 and 3 were identical in make and model, the bizarre pseudo mirroring would happen.  When I changed out #3 to a different make/model everything worked normally.

Also check out [Jake Hilborn's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/396413/187411) answer for displayplacer on github if using a different monitor is not an option